# How to come up with the global path to an Ember controller's property when value binding to a view helper?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's say I have the following controllers

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.PersonStuffController = Ember.Controller.extend({ somethingOnController: [] });
```

with router entries

```
this.resource('person', function() { 
  this.route('stuff'); 
});
```

and routes

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.createRecord('person', {});
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});

App.PersonStuffRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.modelFor('person');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('person', model);
    this.store.find('thing').then(function(things) { 
      controller.set('things', things);
    });
  }
});
```

and models

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'), // Instances of this model will have name values that match a Person instance's property keys

  personStuffPath: function() {
    return 'person.' + this.get('name');
  }.property('name')
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  // A lot of attributes that match the names of App.Thing instance name property values
});
```

In my template for PersonStuff, I have code

```
{{#each thing in things}}
  {{view Ember.Select content=somethingOnController value=thing.personStuffPath.value}}
{{/each}}
```

So what I'm expecting here is a bunch of input fields that are bound to PersonStuffController's person property's properties. Instead I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Path 'person.exampleThingName' must be global if no obj is given.
```

So I modified my Thing model to instead be:

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: 'thingName' }),

  personStuffPath: function() {
    return 'App.PersonStuffController.person.' + this.get('name');
  }.property('name')
});
```

and the error instead becomes:

```
Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "App.PersonStuffController.person" could not be found or was destroyed.
```

This should be the right global path, right? Can I just not do things this way for a reason?

JSBins:

Relative path error: http://jsbin.com/lozayobe/1/edit?html,js,output
Global path error: http://jsbin.com/lozayobe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Is this another hook up to the property based on the value of the property?  http://jsbin.com/lozayobe/2/edit

Comment: Yeah it is. This is just an inquiry into using the '.value' option that can be attached to a path apparently I found used in Ember's source here and there. It seems like this way would be much easier if it weren't for the "could not be founded or was destroyed" error message.

Answer (score 0):

`App.FooController` refers to the class, it's not the actual instance.  In most cases Ember controllers and routes are singletons, so they aren't recreated (except item controllers).  If you wanted to create a global way of accessing a controller you would need to get the controller then add it to some global namespace.

For example (I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it's good to understand how things work):

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  beforeModel: function(){
    var fooInstance = this.controllerFor('foo');
    App.FooControllerInstance = fooInstance;
  }
});
```

Now `App.FooControllerInstance` has the instance of `FooController` where you can map dynamic computed properties.